# How to split up a column into two columns for min and max in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, dplyr

I am busy tidying some weather data, and I've been given a dataframe with dates and wind speed. There are two wind speeds for every date - a minimum and a maximum, but I do not have a third column which differentiates/labels them. How can I split up my data into three columns - column 1 = date (only one per day), column 2 = min wind speed, column 3 = max wind speed.

For example:

```
# example dataframe

df <- data.frame(date = rep(c("2000-01-01", "2000-01-02", "2000-01-03", "2000-01-04"), each = 2),
wind = rep(c(1,2),4))

# sorted dataframe

df2 <- data.frame(date = c("2000-01-01", "2000-01-02", "2000-01-03", "2000-01-04"),
minwind = rep(1,4), maxwind = rep(2,4))
```

I'm sure I can do it with dplyr very easily, but my brain isn't working today!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it with dplyr :)

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(date) %>% 
  mutate(minwind = min(wind),
         maxwind = max(wind)) %>% 
  select(-wind) %>% 
  distinct()
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively with `summarise` from `dplyr` package

```r
df %>% group_by(date) %>% summarise(minwind=min(wind),maxwind=max(wind))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  date       minwind maxwind
  <chr>        <dbl>   <dbl>
1 2000-01-01       1       2
2 2000-01-02       1       2
3 2000-01-03       1       2
4 2000-01-04       1       2
```